# iOS8 table view with multiple sections crashing--having to do with autosizing?

Tags: uitableview, ios8

I don't know how many UITableViews I've made in my life. Hundreds. But this is my first one from scratch on iOS8 and things seem to have changed.

I'm building out my view layer with dummy data, and I can't make a multi-section table work at all. It crashes with an error I'll show below.

In StoreListController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0;
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;


    self.title = @"Stores";

    self.customers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"One", @"Two", @"Three", nil];
    self.stores = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Ooga", @"Booga", nil];

}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return [self.customers count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.stores count] ;
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.customers objectAtIndex:section];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"getting myself a cell");
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    cell.textLabel.text = [self.stores objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

If I return `1` from `tableView:numberOfSectionsInTableView:`, it happily renders me a header labeled "One", and cells labeled "Ooga" and "Booga".

However, if I return the number of headers in the actual array of stores, I get:

```
2014-11-12 07:50:57.234 Stanley-FIL[82428:12358084] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0281b946 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x024a4a97 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x026febd2 -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:] + 210
    3   UIKit                               0x018e9bfc -[UITableViewDataSource tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:] + 50
    4   UIKit                               0x01631139 -[UITableViewController tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:] + 61
    5   UIKit                               0x013f8449 -[UITableView _delegateWantsHeaderForSection:] + 370
    6   UIKit                               0x015b7935 -[UISectionRowData refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:] + 169
...
```

I have tried overriding the UITableViewDelegate method it's calling here (`tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:`), but then I get the same crash looking for heightForFooterInSection:, and then if I implement that, I get the same crash looking for `tableView:indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath:`.

I've NEVER had to explicitly implement all this stuff before. What's going on here? I assume it has to do with the new cell autosizing business, but this is far from "auto"....

EDIT: Then I went ahead and implemented `tableView:indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath:` and it died with the same error trying to run `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`! Which I thought was the whole point of using table cell autosizing to begin with! There's something fundamental I'm misunderstanding, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you connected self.tableView with real one table from .xib?
I've added only this to you code and it works perfect for me (iOS 8.1):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 44.0;
}
```

[image]